# Origin http://www.yoursite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax

I'm having some trouble with some pages on my website. When I try to use the ajax dropdown menu or shopping cart, the pages won't do anything and I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

I've tried to do the same things using other devices/computers and haven't had any issues, everything works fine. I'm' only having this problem on my computer.

Any ideas on how to fix this?